# Filter query with a GROUP BY based on column not in GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table structure and sample data:

`+-------------+------+-------------+
| EmployeeID   | Name  | WorkWeek  |
+--------------+-------+-----------+
|   1          | A     |     1     |
|   2          | B     |     1     |
|   2          | B     |     2     |
|   3          | C     |     1     |
|   3          | C     |     2     |
|   4          | D     |     2     |
+--------------+-------+-----------+`

I am looking to select all employees that only worked week 1 (so in this example, only `employeeid = 1` would be returned.  I am able to get the data with the following query:

`SELECT  EmployeeId, Name
 FROM    SomeTable
 GROUP BY EmployeeId, Name
 HAVING  SUM ( WorkWeek ) = 1;`

To me, the `HAVING SUM( WorkWeek ) = 1` is a hack and this should be handled with some form of a `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` but I cannot wrap my head around how that query would be structured.

Any help would be useful and enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HAVING SUM( WorkWeek ) = 1` may work for week 1 or 2, but will fail for week 3 (since 1+2 = 3).
Use `NOT EXISTS` operator with a subquery instead:

```
SELECT  EmployeeId, Name
FROM    SomeTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM  SomeTable  t2
   WHERE t1.EmployeeId = t2.EmployeeId
     AND t2.WorkWeek  <> 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's exactly why the [`having`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql#examples) clause is for - to filter records according to the aggregated values.

From [w3schools sql tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp):

> The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: I don't disagree that the `HAVING` is necessary, it just seems that the 'correct' way to do this would be `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1` instead of using the `SUM` to add up the Week column